# Hibernate User Type is not registering by default

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I have written a custom User type to handle Date when value is NULL and Used in my pojo as

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person"
)
public class Person {

    private int id;

    @Column(name="dob", length=10)
    @Type(type="poc.datetype.DateTimeUserType")
    private Date dob;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

When try to persist Person in DB,custom type DateTimeUserType is not invoking.

But If I register custom user type to hibernate Configuration then it working.

```
DateTimeUserType dateTimeUserType = new DateTimeUserType();
configuration.registerTypeOverride(dateTimeUserType,new String[] { dateTimeUserType.returnedClass().getName() });
```

I went through many examples of using Custom user type,But no one registered to hibernate configuration.
My question is, is it mandatory to register custom user type to configuration or it should work with out registration ?

Hibernate version using 4.3.5.Final

Comment: Your code is looks fine, have you extended java.util.Date class?
    
    `public class DateTimeUserType extends java.util.Date { .. }`

Comment: No,My Custom type did not extends java.util.date.   public class DateTimeUserType implements UserType {...} ,    Do I need to extend java.util.Date ,If so what could be the reason ?

Comment: I have resolve this issue either by registering userTypes in dialect or to hibernate sessionFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have usertypes/CustomTypes used in pojo classes,then you must register UserTypes/CustomType to hibernate configuration.And it can be done in two ways,either register custom type at dialect or registering to hibernate configuration.
Below is the way to use UserType and registering user type to configuration.

POJO Class :

```
@TypeDefs({
                        @TypeDef(
                         name = "DateTime",
                         defaultForType = org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.class,
                         typeClass = com.common.data.type.WMPersistentLocalDateTime.class
               )
})

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE1"
    ,schema="tr11"
)
public class Table1  implements java.io.Serializable
 {
@Type(type="DateTime")
private LocalDateTime column3;

...getters & setters ....
}
```

UserType registration :

```
sessionFactory.registerTypeOverride(new com.common.data.type.WMPersistentLocalDateTime(), new String[]{"DateTime"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my below post, [UserType api menthods are not called from Criteria Builder query in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126937/usertype-api-menthods-are-not-called-from-criteria-builder-query-in-hibernate)
And my answer there, its a bug in hinerate

it has been fixed in the version 5.2.0.Final